# call oracle procedure using SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: java

I am trying to call an oracle procedure using SimpleJdbcCall.
The procedure was created like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedureName (name IN opt_col)
...
end;
```

opt_col is an oracle TYPE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE opt_col FORCE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
```

Java code like this

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("procedureName");
    call.declareParameters(new SqlParameter(name, Types.ARRAY, "opt_col"));

SimpleJdbcCall.execute(new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("name", ));
```

I cannot find what i must to pass to addValue method

To call the procedure from oracle i use this

```
Begin
    procedureName(opt_col("name"));
End;
```

Comment: You need to pass the value of name variable with which the stored procedure needs to be executed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer. opt_col is a type of table, so i think in the SqlParameter the type must be Types.ARRAY. Maybe it is wrong. What value must i pass to procedure in addValue?